# Differentiate between groups of duplicated values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose I have the following table `table`:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | B       |
| A       | A       |
| A       | A       |   
| C       | D       |
| B       | B       |
| B       | B       |
+---------+---------+
```

I'm querying the DB in order to get all the duplicated rows in `table`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE (column1,
        column2) IN (  SELECT column1,
                              column2
                         FROM table
                     GROUP BY column1,
                              column2
                       HAVING COUNT (*) > 1);
```

and getting this:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | A       |
| A       | A       |   
| B       | B       |
| B       | B       |
+---------+---------+
```

Is there a way to isolate each group of duplicated rows, to save them, and then to get the next group? In the end I would have distinct results sets:

```
Result set #1:
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | A       |
| A       | A       |   
+---------+---------+

Result set #2:
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| B       | B       |
| B       | B       |   
+---------+---------+
```

My idea is to create a sequence in order to enumerate each group, something like this:

```
Result set #1:
+---------+----------+
| column1 | column2  |
+---------+----------+
| A       | A1       |
| A       | A2       |   
+---------+----------+

Result set #2:
+---------+----------+
| column1 | column2  |
+---------+----------+
| B       | B1       |
| B       | B2       |   
+---------+----------+
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select groupnum, column1, column2, seqnum
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by column1, column2) as cnt,
             dense_rank() over (order by column1, column2) as groupnum,
             row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by column1) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by groupnum;
```

Comment: I get the same result, ie. all the duplicated rows.

Comment: @PedroN. . . . Isn't that what you want?

Comment: no, that's what I already have. I want to get the results in separated groups.

Comment: A single SQL `select` only returns one result set.  You can enumerate the duplicates (as this answer now does), but I'm not sure what you mean by "separated groups".

Comment: Separated groups according to the values of the duplicated rows. No way to enumerate all the rows in each group individually instead of enumerating all the duplicated rows?

Comment: @PedroN. . . . Yes, using `dense_rank()` to identify each group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54279/discussion-between-pedro-n-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 0):

From the logical perspective...

```
A       | A
A       | A
```

...is the same thing as...

```
A       | A    | 2
```

So why not just:

```
SELECT column1, column2, COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

?

You'll get a result such as...

```
A       | A    | 2
B       | B    | 2
```

...in other words: each row represents a whole group. You can then easily "expand" each group in the client code if desired.

Comment: How could I isolate and expand each group?

Comment: Just copy the row the number of times that matches the value in the third column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT column1,CASE WHEN RN=1 
                    THEN column2 
                    ELSE CONCAT(column2,convert(varchar(10), (RN-1))) 
               END as column2
FROM
 (SELECT column1,column2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1,column2 ORDER BY column2,column2) as RN
  FROM TableName) T
```

The result will be something like:

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2
A         A
A         A1
A         B
B         B
B         B1
C         D
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/187f7/9).

Comment: I'm not being able to run that statement. I'm working with Oracle Database 11g.

Comment: @PedroN.: How about now?